# How to Call a Clojure Function from C?

Tags: c, clojure, ffi

Suppose we have a clojure function `(defn some-func ...)`. How could one call this function from C?

Comment: You can call Clojure from Java, and Java from C, but it might be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

C does not allow native clojure functions. But they can be implemented e.g: [A Clojure implementation on top of C](https://github.com/schani/clojurec)

For calling from C++ see: [Can I call clojure code from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650485/can-i-call-clojure-code-from-c)