# Calling C++ from clojure

Tags: c++, clojure

Is it possible to call C++ libraries like CGAL or VTK from Clojure? Can this be  possibly  done if C++ functions are wrapped with C interface functions, like Haskell does with the c2hs tool and its excellent C FFI?

[Can I call clojure code from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650485/can-i-call-clojure-code-from-c)
this question asks for the reverse,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several alternatives here:

- you can do it the same way as Java does - via [JNI (Java Native Interface)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). There is a complete example of using [clojure with JNI](https://github.com/jakebasile/clojure-jni-example).
- there is a [JNA project](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) that allows to have access to native libraries without writing bridge as JNI requires.  There is an [old (2009th) blog post](https://nakkaya.com/2009/11/16/java-native-access-from-clojure/) about using JNA with Clojure.
- for C++ better alternative could be [JavaCpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).
- generate Java bindings via [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) & access them as normal Java methods.